What does It refer to in 'It is as if nothing has changed.'
Does it refer to the situation that is described before, or just preparatory 'it'?

He has no faith in the current softening of the American line towards
the Palestinians, which he says is a replica of their approach during
the Gulf war. "Whenever the US needs the Arabs, they are ready to
offer a carrot," he says. "In 1991 the Arab world was lured into the
Gulf war against Iraq because they were promised that they would be
compensated by a just solution of the Palestinian problem. The
Americans sent letters of reassurance to all the parties and the Arab
states went to Madrid to negotiate on the basis of those assurances.
It is 10 years since Madrid and nothing has happened. Now the same
scenario is being repeated. Strangely enough, it is even the same
people - Cheney, Powell, a Bush. It is as if nothing has
changed. People in the Arab world will see that our leaders are
deceived again. Those who repeat their lessons are very bad pupils,
and we are very bad pupils. We don't learn from our mistakes, so we
are doomed to repeat them."

'There isn't a target in Afghanistan worth a $1m missile'- The Guardian

It's probably fair to say that in this exact context, it really makes no difference!

Ten years passed, so it's not recent: It is as if nothing has changed in that many years.

The "it" is not referential here, but a dummy element  serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position.

Let's approach the question by comparing two possibilities:

Nothing has changed.
It is as if nothing has changed.

The first is a bald statement that there has been no change whatsoever.
The second concedes, with as if, that something is different (is it merely that time has passed?) but there has been no change in the state of affairs.
It is not anaphoric there in the sense of referring back to a particular noun, but neither is it absolutely empty; it is a reference to the Present.
Machine parsers have no sense of Time and World but language as spoken by mortal beings does.

I wouldn't go along with all that you say. The pronoun "it" is semantically empty, hence the term 'dummy pronoun'. It's the tense of the verb that reflects the time: "It is ..." / "It was...".

@BillJ  We just happen to disagree and there's no way to settle the disagreement with terminology. I don't think it is empty, but vast. It is the world of the speaker.

'Vast'? So what, according to you, is its semantic content? It's not anaphoric, nor temporal, so what can it possible be?

It is the present state of "things", the speaker's world.  There's a deictic aspect to it.

I might be able to understand you saying that about the whole clause, but not about the humble "it", whose sole purpose here is to serve the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position. Btw, how can dummy "it" possibly be deontic, a modal meaning requirement or permission. You are misleading learners by saying that.

I didn't say deontic but deictic.

Sorry, I sloppily misread your comment. But how can dummy "it" have a deictic aspect to it?

I understand "it" in utterances like "It is as if" to refer to "things as they are" as seen from the speaker's perspective or origo -- to use a term that often comes up in theoretical discussions of deixis. But I mean an origo on a contextual stage that is far broader than the speaker's local orientation in space in respect to the Near and the Far, the Here and the There, the This and the That, as with demonstratives.  It's the speaker's worldview-center.

That won't work because third person is not a deictic category.

What person are this and that in? And it's not third person but an oblique form of the first person in that it expresses a speaker-world relationship.  It's a kind of speech-act deixis.

The demonstratives "this" and "that" are not pronouns but determinatives.

@BillJ:  this and that are deictic and refer to something "near" and "distant" from the speaker's perspective.  I don't see what grammatical person has to do with it at all, and why it, which I say is used to refer to an existential state of affairs from the speaker's perspective, cannot be said to do so because it is the third person.  What does grammatical person have to do with deixis such that it cannot be involved with it?  What makes the third person and deixis oil and water?

You're doing it again: attaching a meaning to the whole clause and then seeking to apply it to dummy "it", which makes no sense. FYI, dummy "it" also occurs as subject in extraposition, and of course as the so-called "|weather "it". It does not refer to contextually salient entitities, and it cannot be replaced by other 3rd person personal pronouns, hence the term 'dummy'.

@BillJ    I'm not saying that it refers to "contextually salient entities" but  that it refers to  the very Context itself, from the speaker's perspective, and as broadly or as narrowly as the semantics require.

It is a pronoun and therefore refers back to a noun or idea earlier in the narrative. Sometimes that reference is clear, sometimes it's more fuzzy or ambiguous.
Consider the following imaginary story.

Today I went for a walk along the beach. The wind was blowing strong, the tide was high and the waves were tossing seaweed onto the sand. It was very cold and challenging.

In this setting, what exactly was cold and challenging? A cold wind? A cold beach? A challenging walk because the beach was messy at high tide? Cold sea spray from the waves?
In this case the likely reference is to the story as a whole. It introduces the final sentence, and that sentence can be read as a summary of what has gone before.
I think the same process is applicable in the OP. It is as if nothing has changed means "Put all these factors together and the impression given is that nothing has changed".

The "it" is not referential here, but a dummy (meaningless) element serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position.
